# Get two differents elements with awaitMessage with discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm developing my Discord bot in JavaScript with the discord.js library, and I want to retrieve **two values** with the **awaitMessages** function.

I tested the code below but it doesn't work.

The code is as follows:

```js
message.channel.send("Quel message voulez vous ?").then(function () {
    message.channel
        .awaitMessages((response) => message.content, {
            max: 1,
            time: 60000,
            errors: ["time"],
        })
        .then((collected) => {
            let msg = collected.first().content;

            if (!dbBvnMsg.getContent(`${message.guild.id}-msg`)) {
                dbBvnMsg.add(`${message.guild.id}-msg`, msg);
                console.log("Ici 1");
            } else {
                dbBvnMsg.set(`${message.guild.id}-msg`, msg);
                console.log("Ici 2");
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.send("Quel channel ?").then(() => {
                message.channel
                    .awaitMessages((res) => message.content, {
                        max: 2,
                        time: 60000,
                        errors: ["time"],
                    })
                    .then((c) => {
                        let channel = c.first().mentions.channels.first().id;

                        if (dbBvnChan.getValue(`${message.guild.id}-channel`)) {
                            dbBvnChan.add(
                                `${message.guild.id}-channel`,
                                channel
                            );
                        } else {
                            dbBvnChan.set(
                                `${message.guild.id}-channel`,
                                channel
                            );
                        }
                    });
            });
        })
        .catch("Non");
});
```

Can you help me?

Cordially,
SKKYZ3R.

Comment: Could you tell how it "doesn't work"? At what point in the code does the result differ from what you expect?

Comment: I say that it doesn't work because in the part that gets the channel, it doesn't fit in the .json and it doesn't get the value

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolve! I made it with

```js
message.channel.createMessageCollector()
```

Thanks for answers!